# put selected values from textbox and dropdown to a basket like amazon

Tags: php, jquery, cart

I have a PHP survey form in which there is a question "Which are your favourite movies?". for this question, I put a dropdown which enable users to select movies by title or by actor. If user select "by title", a textbox (auto-complete) will be shown where he can insert a movie name. If user select "by actor", a new window will be opened containing a textbox where user should insert an actor name, then a dynamic dropdown is populated showing list of movies by that actor.

### Question:

How can I get the selected movies (from textbox and also dropdown in new window) and put them in a basket like amazon shopping cart? I searched a lot, but I really could not find the solution.. I can put the selected values in a new dropdown, but my professor asked me to use the same method like amazon and put them in a basket!!

### UPDATE:

Here is what I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link type="text/css" href="res/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="movienames">
<select id="selectType" name="source" style="size=5px; width:100px; height:30px;">
  <option value="">MoviesBy</option>
  <option value="byTitle">byTitle</option>
  <option value="byActor">byActor</option>
  <option value="byDirector">byDirector</option>
</select>

<div id="m_scents">
<p>
 <label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
<input class="autofill4" type="textbox" name= "q27[]" id="q" style="display:none;" placeholder="Enter movie titles here" />
<!--<a href="#" id="addScnt4">Add more movies</a>-->
<input type="button" value=">> Add to selected list >>" id="btnMove" style="display:none;"/>
<input name="s" value="all" type="hidden"/>
<label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
</p>
</div>
<select id="selectedItems" name="selectedItems[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px; size:10px;">
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#selectType").change(function () {

               if ($(this).val() == "byTitle") {
                    $("#q").show();
                    $("#btnMove").show();
                    $("#q").focus();
                    $("#q").autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        delay:5,
                        source: "mona.php",
                        focus: function( event, ui ){
                             event.preventDefault(); //This prevent the inserted text to be changed while moving in suggest list 
                        return false;
                        },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                             $(this).val( ui.item.movieName );
                              return false;
                        }
                    }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                      return $("<li></li>")
                          .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                          .append( "<a>" + (item.posterLink?"<img class='imdbImage' src='imdbImage.php?url=" + item.posterLink + "' />":"") + "<span class='imdbTitle'>" + item.movieName + "</span>" + "<div class='clear'></div></a>" )
                          .appendTo( ul );
                        };
                 } else 
                   if ($(this).val() == "byActor"){     
                            window.open("target.html","_blank","height=400,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
                    }
            });
   });

$('#btnMove').on('click', function (d) {
       var selected = $("#q").val();
       if (selected.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            d.preventDefault();
       }
       $('#selectedItems').append(new Option(selected));
       var title = new Option(selected);
       $("#q").val("");
       d.preventDefault();
   });      

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is target.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="res/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js"type="text/javascript"type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
 <p>
  <input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags" placeholder="Enter an actor/actress name here" />
 </p>
 <p>
  <select id="movieName" name="movieName[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style="display:none;">
  </select>
 </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
     source: "actorsauto.php",
     minLength: 2,
     focus: function( event, ui ){
            event.preventDefault(); //This prevent the inserted text to be changed while moving in suggest list 
            return false;
            },
     select: function (event, ui){      
                    var selectedVal = ui.item.value;
                    $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
                         console.log(response);                                       
                         $("#movieName").html(response).show();
                     });
             }
    }); 
  });
 </script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone kindly inform me if there is any tutorial or sample that I can use for this purpose?

All ideas are highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far so that we can help you. Post your code.

Comment: Well, based on the selection you made, you can create a new ajax call creating your 'basket'. Q: basket == $_session?

Comment: @mOna From what I see, when a user clicks the `#btnMove` the information selected, should append to `#selectedItems`. Where is the `#selectedItems` element located in the markup?

Comment: @Naruto: Thanks for your comment, but my problem is I don't know how to cretae baskets.. I asked if there is some tutorial I can follow?

Comment: a basket can be created in many ways.. I would simply create a javascript object/array.

Comment: @CodeGodie:sorry since the code was too long, I didn't paste it completely, I added it now. (It is a just a simple dropdown where I passed selected values to it, but I need to use a basket instead of this dropdown)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64255/discussion-between-codegodie-and-mona).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok for the first part I would do the following:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #basket{
            padding: 10px;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
        }

        #basket h3{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="movienames">
        <select id="selectType" name="source" style="font-size:15px; width:100px; height:30px;">
            <option value="">MoviesBy</option>
            <option value="byTitle">byTitle</option>
            <option value="byActor">byActor</option>
            <option value="byDirector">byDirector</option>
        </select>

        <div id="m_scents">
            <p>
                <label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
                <input class="autofill4" type="textbox" name= "q27[]" id="q" style="display:none;" placeholder="Enter movie titles here" />
                <!--<a href="#" id="addScnt4">Add more movies</a>-->
                <input type="button" value=">> Add to selected list >>" id="btnMove" style="display:none;"/>
                <input name="s" value="all" type="hidden"/>
                <label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="basket">
            <h3>Basket</h3>
            <div id="basket_content">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
var master_basket = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectType").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "byTitle") {
            $("#q").show();
            $("#btnMove").show();
            $("#q").focus();
            $("#q").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                delay: 5,
                source: "mona.php",
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault(); //This prevent the inserted text to be changed while moving in suggest list 
                    return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).val(ui.item.movieName);
                    return false;
                }
            }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a>" + (item.posterLink ? "<img class='imdbImage' src='imdbImage.php?url=" + item.posterLink + "' />" : "") + "<span class='imdbTitle'>" + item.movieName + "</span>" + "<div class='clear'></div></a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
            };
        } else
        if ($(this).val() == "byActor") {
            window.open("target.html", "_blank", "height=400,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
        }
    });
});

$('#btnMove').on('click', function(d) {
    d.preventDefault();
    var selected = $("#q").val();
    if (selected.length == 0) {
        alert("Nothing to move.");
        d.preventDefault();
    } else {
        addToBasket(selected);
    }
    $("#q").val("");
});

function addToBasket(item) {
    master_basket.push(item);
    showBasketObjects();
}

function showBasketObjects() {
    $("#basket_content").empty();
    $.each(master_basket, function(k, v) {
        $("#basket_content").append("<div>" + v + "</div>");
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time and kind support.. I tried it, the logic is what I want , but How can I show a real basket? should I use the image? then, how can I put values in that basket?!:|